# set permission automatically to all subfolder and subfiles in specific folder

Tags: centos, permissions, directory

I want to set a folder such that anything created within it (directories, files) inherit default permissions and group ,  by anyuser (root also)

so , the content of this folder will be deleted by my user

Comment: This question is unclear: What OS? - I'm assuming Linux. Are you wanting a directory where _anybody_ (including root) writes here will always have a specific user/group? Doesn't work that way on Linux although root can easily change any file/directory ownership recursively.

Comment: I use Centos Linux .. i am waiting for a folder where anyboody can write here , (subfolder and file) , so i can delete the content with my user ; without use sudo

Answer (score 2):

So, you'll need to be using a filesystem that supports User and Group ACL's (ext4 and xfs both do; but ext4 needs to be mounted with "acl" option set - "mount -o defaults,acl", for example)

Then you just need to set the default facl to include full permissions for your user and r/x for everyone else.  Say the directory the files need to be in is called /directory and your user is called MYUSER, and you put "all other users" in a group called USERS, you'd do something like this:

`setfacl -d -m u:MYUSER:rwx /directory
setfacl -d -m g:USERS:r-x /directory
setfacl -m g:USERS:r-x /directory
setfacl -m u:MYUSER:rwx /directory`

Now any new files created in /directory are readable, writable, and executable by you; but only readable and executable by the USERS group.

To learn more about the use of filesystem ACLs, you can consult [RedHat's excellent documentation](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists)

Comment: Nice solution. I was trying to avoid having the OP dive into SELinux configuration

Comment: Agreed - technically, ACLs aren't SE Linux.  They're complicated in their own right, but in a way that  builds more naturally on filesystem permissions than SE Linux contexts do.

Comment: No , but i need also the file is writable by author ; in this case , any user can write a file , i can delete them

Comment: Deleting and writing are the same permission.  If you can write, you can delete - there's no good way around that issue (short of a complicated architecture where users write files in one place and a sync process of some sort - say lsync or some such - moves them to a place where another user can delete them).

Answer (score 1):

> folder where anyboody can write here , (subfolder and file)

You can set the main folder's permissions: chmod 0777  but other users cannot access it unless the same permissions exist all the way to the root directory - not a good security measure in home directories. In addition SELinux permissions may cause problems with users writing outside their home directories.

> i can delete the content with my user ; without use sudo

Deleting files created in such a directory would still have to be done as sudo/root unless the files are all created with a specific group with group write permissions and your user is also a member.

In short, what you're asking to do is not really feasible.

Comment: Actually, it's feasible - you'll just need to use FileSystem ACL's instead of Filesystem Permissions (setfacl/getfacl instead of chmod/ls)

Comment: How i can use acl ?